# Batch Running .exe in subdirectories

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file, format, command

So I have an exe (xmllint.exe) to pretty print some XML-files in specific subdirectories. The xmllint.exe is in my maindirectory, where my script is. Here is what I have so far

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /D /r %%d in (./*targetfolder) do (
    pushd %%d
    for %%x in (*.xml) do (
        ::Get the filename, without the .old-extension
        set "filename=%%~nx"
        set "extension=.xml"

        ren %%x %%~x.old

        ::Concatenate filename and extension
        set "finalname=!filename!!extension!"
        xmllint.exe %%x >> !finalname!

        del %%~x.old
    )
    popd
)
```

But of course it doesn't run the xmllint.exe in the subdirectories, because it can't find it.

Comment: Replace `xmllint.exe` with `"path\to\xmllint.exe"`.  Or if `xmllint.exe` exists in the same directory as the batch script, you could do `"%~dp0\xmllint.exe"`.  Or you could add the directory containing `xmllint.exe` to your `%PATH%`.

Comment: Thanks! The %~dp0 was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking is `%~dp0` see `call /?` of `for /?`

But I don't get it, if you rename the file before xmlint, how you will be able to use `%%x` in xmlint?

```vb
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem :: set the target folder first with:
set "targetfolder=c:\path\of\target"

for /D /r %%a in (%targetfolder%\*.xml) do (

    rem :: make a copy
    copy "%%~a" "%%~dpna.old"

    "%~dp0\xmllint.exe" "%%~dpna.old">> "%%~a"

    del "%%~dpna.old"
)
```

---

Edit, Changed `FOR /R` should work now.

```vb
@echo off
rem :: set the target folder first with:
set "targetfolder=c:\path\of\target"
for /R %targetfolder% %%a in (*.xml) do (
    rem :: make a copy
    copy "%%~a" "%%~dpna.old"
    "%~dp0xmllint.exe" "%%~dpna.old">> "%%~a"
    del "%%~dpna.old"
)
```

**Important note**: you have to change the line:

`"%~dp0xmllint.exe" "%%~dpna.old">> "%%~a"`
to
`"%~dp0xmllint.exe" "%%~dpna.old"> "%%~a"`

By keeping only one `>` it will recreate the file instead of appending to the file.